What is the best way to convert 120v 15amp to 30amp circuit?
I bought an inexpensive tankless water heater off Amazon because it ran on 120v. It's to heat water for an outdoor tub up to at least 85-ish degrees, so it doesn't have to deliver really hot water, just warm water.
Here's the problem... the product description on Amazon did not include that it would require a 30 Amp circuit.  It did say it was 3000 watts, but I'm a novice and didn't realize it would be 30 amps. And, it has a standard 3-prong 120v type plug on the cord.
Is there an easy way to "convert" two 15 Amp outlets into a 30 amp circuit?  I've looked at the Camco RV converter, but that leaves me with a standard 30 Amp lockable female plug which the heater can't plug into.

Something doesn't add up here. Please provide a link to the product or more technical information. I'm surprised, even for Amazon, that what you describe would be sold.

You could try it on the 15 amp receptacle as is.  It will either trip the breaker, take a long time to heat, or it will work okay and there is a typo.  Without a UL/ELT/CSA label, it is still unsafe/not code legal to use.  Chinese translations are not always correct/make sense.

@crip659 if OP's description is accurate (I think and hope it is not) then relying on the breaker in this situation is dangerous.  A 30A load on a 20A breaker will take a minute or several minutes to pop, depending on the breaker, and if it behaves to spec. If you keep doing that day after day you might discover that some part of your wiring is not able to withstand this, or that the breaker doesn't perform perfectly well.   These are not things that get tested on site so I wouldn't count THAT HEAVILY on the breaker.

Yeah, deliberate overload is a bad idea. I've seen hot cord plugs more times than I can count on jobsites, and that was usually out on the dirt. Don't do it in your home.

Amazon Marketplace is all 3rd party sellers same as eBay, Wish and Temu.   The seller is in China whose courts won't accept our lawsuits, so they have zero liability for shoveling junk or lying to people.  The "110V" is a trick to get you to buy it, thinking you can plug it into any common outlet.  It really is 110V but at absurd amps a normal socket can’t supply.  Send it back and realize Amazon Marketplace is a junk site like Wish/ eBay.

Send the heater back.
Having a standard 120v plug for something that requires 30 amps sounds like a fire waiting to happen.
I bet my house it does not have UL testing lab label on it, so your insurance will keep all your money if you make a claim.
Plugs have a certain design feature so you do not plug a 15 amp plug into a 30 amp circuit.
For a 30 amp circuit, you will need to add a new circuit with a 30 amp breaker and 10 gauge wires/cable and a 30 amp receptacle.

To answer just part of your question, "can you combine two 15A circuits", the answer is no but if you want to cobble together double the heating power without running new cable to the location of the heater, it might be possible.  So long as the outlet there is the only one on the circuit breaker, or you are willing to permanently disconnect and remove any other outlets on the same circuit, you can convert the circuit to 240V by replacing the breaker.  Then you buy a 15A or 20A 240V heater.  For example, if it's a 20A circuit you can use this 4800W heater.  There are some details that could get in your way but it's a possible way forward.

Converting to a 240v receptacle should require changing to a 6-15/6-20 receptacle also.

@crip659 Or hard wire.  But good point.    My answer is not a step-by-step, just a pointer to an approach that might work without pulling cable.
